# TypeScript how to create a function with conditional return type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, union-types

I would like to write a function with a conditional return type. If the function gets passed a 'val1' as argument it returns a string type, if 'val2' returns number type and so on.

Simple example

playground: [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/v2/en/play#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)

```js
const store = {
  val1: 'string',
  val2: 1,
  val3: true
};

type INames = keyof typeof store; // "val1" | "val2" | "val3"
const getFromStore = (paramName: INames) => {
  return store[paramName];
};

const res = getFromStore('val1'); // return type is string | number | boolean instead of string
res.split(''); // error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const store = {
    val1: 'string',
    val2: 1,
    val3: true
};

const getFromStore = <K extends keyof typeof store>(paramName: K) => {
    return store[paramName];
};

const res = getFromStore('val1');
res.split('');
```

Answer (score -2):

split function work on the string, Please look out [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

toFixed function work on the Number, Please look out [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

So, if you are converting res and res2 in proper format and then apply proper function. Might be you can catch your expected result.

I have done some changes to your code. (Converting res into the string and Converting res2 into a number). Please look out your changed code [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=14&pc=35#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) and [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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)